# Can an iOS7 device act as an iBeacon?

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Can an iOS7 device act as an **iBeacon** and figure out when other iOS7 devices come in its range? Do those other iOS7 devices need to have Bluetooth turned on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An iOS device with BluetoothLE can act as an iBeacon yes.

Check out the AirLocate example code at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013#

Being an iBeacon doesn't give feedback about devices that come into range so you'd have to implement that yourself. ie you'd have to have the devices that detect the iBeacon then tell the iBeacon they'd seen it through some other means.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: The device that is the receiver, does that device need to have the application running (the app that is checking for iBeacons)? Or can the application that comes into the iBeacon range be closed or in the background and it will receive a notification when it enters the iBeacon's area?

Comment: Yep, Check out the docs for `CLLocationManager`. "In iOS, the regions you register with the location manager persist between launches of your application. If a region crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event."

Comment: @MikePollard have you tried this with iBeacon regions? I've been unable to get it to work when the app has been force-closed from multitasking. It works when the app is in the background (even if it's been in the background for a long time and the OS has closed it), but not if it was force-closed.

Comment: @MikePollard unfortunately, the link is dead, could you please suggest any other location to look for an example (preferably in swift). Thanks!

Comment: @MikePollard An iOS Device can act as am iBeacon in the background?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, an iOS device can act as a beacon, from iPhone 4s and up (Bluetooth 4.0 required).

You publish a beacon by passing the dictionary from [`[CLBeaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013054-CH1-SW16) to [`[CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW9).

Publishing a beacon will not give you any feedback on devices, you'll have to scan for others publishing a beacon.

As for backgrounding, you can not publish a beacon in the background, your app needs to be running in the foreground for that. Scanning is possible in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an iOS7 device can act as an iBeacon.  You can do exactly  what you are suggesting if you have an app installed on all phones, and you also write a web service. This would allow phone A to see phones B and C when they are nearby:

1. Your app on Phone A acts as an iBeacon advertising its presence.
2. Phones B and C see this iBeacon, waking up your app to make a call to your web service reporting that they both see Phone A's transmission.
3. Your app on Phone A queries this web service, which returns a list of phones that see Phone A.  In this example, the list includes Phones B and C.   Your app updates its display with this list.

All phones would need Bluetooth LE, have it turned on, and have your app installed. They would also need internet connectivity to call the web service.

Comment: Just for kicks - here is a quick way to get started on ibeacons https://github.com/manishnath/iBeaconCenter/tree/master

Comment: This is one another good example i got..., check it out, https://github.com/nicktoumpelis/HiBeacons

Answer (score 1):

If you're not set on using iBeacons, this project uses Bluetooth LE to share an array of ids between nearby phones- [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

You could set an ID for the user of each phone, share them between the phones over Bluetooth LE using the SimpleShare project (even while in background mode), and then query a web service to find out more information about the user with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

One point that didn't come out clearly from the previous answers is that in order for the publishing to work (for example in David's answer's Phone A) the application that started publishing must be in foreground.

From the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html):

> While your app is in the background, the local name is not advertised
>   and all service UUIDs are placed in the overflow area.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, an iOS 7 device *can* act as an iBeacon, so long as it Bluetooth LE technology.

> To use iBeacon, you need iOS 7 or later, Bluetooth turned on, and a compatible iOS device:
>
> - iPhone 4s or later
> - iPad (3rd generation) or later
> - iPad mini or later
> - iPod touch (5th generation) or later.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6048