# Does AirLocate only look for particular UUIDs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluez, ibeacon

I've been testing some iBeacons -- hen I set the UUID of the beacon to something other than the default it isn't picked up by AirLocate.

Is AirLocate only looking for particular beacon UUIDs or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AirLocate works differently depending on whether you are ranging or monitoring.  When you are monitoring, you can choose from any one of eight built-in ProximityUUIDs to monitor, and you can optionally also choose to monitor based on a major and minor identifier.  While you can manually edit one of the built-in ProximityUUIDs, changing one only affects the currently monitored region -- it doesn't modify the list of the eight built-in identifiers.

The eight built-in ProximityUUIDS are:

```
E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
5A4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B7E5
74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935
112ebb9d-b8c9-4abd-9eb3-43578bf86a41
22a17b43-552a-4482-865f-597d4c10bacc
33d8e127-4e58-485b-bee7-266526d8ecb2
44f506a4-b778-4c4e-8522-157aac0efabd
552452fe-f374-47c4-bfad-9ea4165e1bd9
```

When ranging, AirLocate looks for any iBeacon with *any* of the above eight built-in ProximityUUIDs simultaneously.  There is no way to manually choose a smaller list to range with, nor is there any way to manually edit the UUIDs.  It is also not possible to set a major or minor for filtering the iBeacons that are ranged.

If you want to use AirLocate to range for an iBeacon whose ProximityUUID is not in this list, you must modify the source code to add your own ProximityUUID.

Comment: There are only 3 default UUID in AirLocate projects. Where are the rest 5 come from?

Answer (score 1):

as seen in [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Listings/AirLocate_APLDefaults_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013430-AirLocate_APLDefaults_m-DontLinkElementID_14)

E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0

5A4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B7E5

74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935

note sure where the others listed above are referenced.