# How to turn Mac into iBeacon

Tags: macos, bluetooth, osx-mavericks, ibeacon

Has anyone tried turning MAC into iBeacon. I have done this for iOS device and want a similar independent app for MAC with some UI as well. I heard the new APIs on mavericks supports iBeacon and we can use them for UI purpose as well. Any pointers/sample code/documentation would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this project for some great sample code on how to achieve this in Mavericks: https://github.com/timd/MactsAsBeacon

It's based on the following blog post: http://www.blendedcocoa.com/blog/2013/11/02/mavericks-as-an-ibeacon/

Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

At Radius Networks, we just released a product that will provide you this functionality called MacBeacon.
We hope you find it as useful a tool as we do in designing, testing and iterating on iBeacon-based solutions.

http://www.radiusnetworks.com/macbeacon-app.html

Comment: I see its a paid app with $9.99 price. Do you guys ship the code as well?

Comment: It is our product, so no, but this answer provide the basics of how to accomplish the same functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410398/turn-macbook-into-ibeacon/19990935#19990935

Comment: why is this dead?