# Core Bluetooth act as Beacon

Tags: ios, swift

A device with iBeacon technology,can be used to establish a region around an object. This allows an iOS device to determine
when it has entered or left the region.(Example - whenever we come across a beacon device, it estimated the distance(range)of device and gives a notification to the devices ). So is that possible to use core bluetooth do the same functionality?

Comment: You want to transform your iPhone into an iBeacon? If YES: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274286/can-an-ios7-device-act-as-an-ibeacon

Comment: I want my iphone to sense broadcasting events from any device in range.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own iBeacon-like functionality in your app, but you could not duplicate the OS level support. It would be a lot of work, but it's possible.

HOWEVER...

With iBeacons the location manager takes care of beacon notifications for you, and will notify your app about enter/exit beacon regions even if your app is suspended or not running at the time. Third party apps can't do that. Period.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with core bluetooth notifying app about enter/exit beacon regions even if your app is suspended

Comment: "Third party apps can't do that. Period."  No.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html